# my django can't generate models from oracle database

Tags: django, oracle

I am building django project upon oracle database, after I set my database in django settings, I use command **python manage.py inspectdb** to generate oracle tables, but there is an error:

```
> Unicode DecodeError: 'utf-8 codec can't decode bytes in position
> 82-83:invalid continuation byte
```

What can I do ?  The oracle is not install in my local pc.
I tried to set local env `path:NLS_LANG=SIMPLIFIED CHINESE_CHINA.ZHS16GBK`, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Django Database [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#encoding):

> Encoding
>
> Django assumes that all databases use UTF-8 encoding. Using other
>   encodings may result in unexpected behavior such as “value too long”
>   errors from your database for data that is valid in Django. See the
>   database specific notes below for information on how to set up your
>   database correctly.

You first need to convert your database to use UTF-8 encoding before you can use it with Django. I don't think any other encoding is supported.

If our Oracle database is UTF-8 encoded, check that you meet all the requirements:

> Django supports Oracle Database Server versions 11.2 and higher.
>   Version 5.2 or higher of the cx_Oracle Python driver is required.